# Deleted file geodatabase from hosted feature layer on ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, file-geodatabase

For ArcGIS Online, if I delete the source file geodatabase used to publish a hosted feature layer, would I need to recreate the whole layer?

The layer is also attached to a web map application.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in the particular case you're referring too, nothing would happen to the hosted layer and map.

HOWEVER, per the [help](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/manage-hosted-layers.htm) (while not your exact situation, but similar):

> If you delete the file from which a hosted layer was published, you'll
> receive a message warning you there are dependent layers. You will not
> be prevented from deleting the file, but if you do delete it, certain
> functionality may no longer be available. For example, if you delete
> the tile package from which a hosted tile package was published, maps
> that contain the hosted tile layer cannot be taken offline.

From my experience, unless the fGDB in your space is massive (like many GBs), it is using the simple storage credits which are incredibly cheap. Basically, unless there is a  cost concern, it probably doesn't get you anywhere to delete the source fGDB.

Update - here is the [specific note for deleting the fGDB](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/faq.htm#DELETE_SRC):

> ...the layer continues to draw as expected. However, certain
> functionality that requires access to the source data may no longer
> work...
>
> If you delete a source shapefile, file geodatabase, CSV file, or
> Microsoft Excel file from Content, the Overwrite option on the hosted
> feature layer's item page is no longer available.

Comment: My issue is I need to overwrite the layer, it's a process that needs to be done weekly. So I'm seeing if there is a quicker solution than recreating the whole feature layer

Comment: I'm not seeing how your question about deleting the source fGDB has anything to do with a quicker way to recreate the whole layer. Next time, please define your entire workflow/problem rather than one piece.

Comment: Apologies, this is my first question here and I will be more clear for the future.